# Logout on the site does not work

Tags: python, django

I have recently updated django from 1.6 to 1.11. Among many other problems (already solved) I have problem with logging out.

Steps:
1. I log in on the site (standard django auth protocol used).

2. I perform some actions on the site as logged user.
3. I log out. I see "logout compleated" (standard django function), looks like I am not logged in.
4. I click somewhere on the site and I am logged in again.

When I click log out, session is delated, but after another action it shows up again.
I have no idea how to give you more details, does anyone had any similar problem?

Comment: Can you post a small code snippet of your logout view function?

Comment: post your logout code here in the post.

Comment: I do not have my own code, standard django function (django.contrib.auth.views.logout) is used. Not modified in any way. One more thing - when I disable cache in browser then logout works fine.

Comment: How are you caching the site? You cache will be the problem here.

Comment: For debugging now all the cache on the site is turned off (dummy cache) but logout still does not work

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the problem? Anyone? :)